# Game story where a lower score is better

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-stream-story

My company is producing a racing game where the best score is the fastest time. Facebook publishes the time as a regular point score, where a higher score is better. This of course is turning it all upside down.

Is there a way to control how a game's score shown in a story? Ideally we would like to show "seconds" instead of points as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Scores API currently only supports 'higher is better' for scores. 
If you can't rework your scoring scheme to take this into account, consider using Open Graph actions instead - you can have the aggregations which appear on a user's Timeline ordered by whichever field of the object and action you need them to be ordered by,

Comment: _If_ you want to rework it, you could just compute a difference – let’s say the _slowest_ time that can be reached is a thousand seconds, then you just subtract the actual seconds from that. 1000-300 secs means 700 points, a better time of 150 secs comes out to 1000-150 = 850 points …